# JQueryMobile not working on the second page

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a phonegap project for android using jquery mobile. The app worked find but I needed to add a new page to the start of the app. Once I have done this jquery mobile doesn't work when I navigate to the second page. Does anybody know any reasons for this?

All of my javascript/jquery is located on main.js

here are the first and seconds pages

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap Demo With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgandjqm-style-override.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.2.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

    <!-- CDN Respositories: For production, replace lines above with these uncommented minified versions -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>-->
    </head>
  <body data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <img src="images/joycard.png" alt="JoyCard" class="banner">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <h3>Partner News</h3>

            <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                    <h3>13 Kanus</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>A Lounge</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Kino</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Action Sport Berlin</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>13 Kanus</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>A Lounge</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Kino</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Action Sport Berlin</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dictum, est nec adipiscing interdum, felis diam pharetra leo, ut tempus magna arcu eu enim. Etiam facilisis condimentum neque tempus bibendum.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="example">
                <h2 onclick="toIndex();">To the app</h2>
            </div>

        </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap Demo With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgandjqm-style-override.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.2.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


    <!-- CDN Respositories: For production, replace lines above with these uncommented minified versions -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>-->
    </head>
  <body data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <img src="images/joycard.png" alt="JoyCard" class="banner">
        </div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="categoriesList();" class="ui-btn-active">KATEGORIEN</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="mapDetails();">IN DER N&Auml;HE</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="allPartners();">ALLE PARTNER</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar --> 


        <div id="list" data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end jqm content -->

        <div id="allPartners" data-role="content">  
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
            </ul>
        </div><!--/all partners list -->    

        <div id="loctext" ></div>

        <div id="map_canvas" class="mapView"></div>

        <div id="menu" data-role="content" class="menu" onClick="hideMenu();">
                    <a href="news.html" class="menu-item"><img src="images/news.png" alt="News"></a>
                    <a href="contact.html" class="menu-item"><img src="images/contact.png" alt="Contact"></a>
                    <a href="info.html" class="menu-item"><img src="images/info.png" alt="Info"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this really supposed to be missing the .js on the end - src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.2.min"

Comment: All the script tags(apart from the google maps) where generated from a wizard so I guess so unless the wizard is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is the link that takes you to the second page?

```
<h2 onclick="toIndex();">To the app</h2>
```

What does this function do?  Is it using this function:

```
$.mobile.changePage("secondpage.html");
```

Comment: I have actually restructured the project now. And have div tages with data-role="page" so I am just using 1 html file.

Comment: but yes it was using that function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using now onlye one html, you msut referer the pages with the id:

< div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id=¨first_page¨ >

< div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id=¨second_page¨ >
.............
Go to the first page
..........

One importat thing you must know is that the first page in the list of pages inside one html file will be first, so in this case first_page will me showed after the splash screen.

In the other case (using different html files) isn´t necesary include de styles in the seconds, third and other pages that arent the index.html, becouse all is loaded by default with js. So first is lodaded the index.html and then the jqm stats to work, then the other pages will be loaded with ajax at least you disable then or use external rol.